# AJAX Request stopped working

Tags: ajax

I had this ajax request working and now it has stopped.  I don't believe I changed any of the code, but who knows.  I did download and upload some new jquery but the ajax request doesn't use jquery.  Anyways, this is a football game picking website and I need to fix it quick.  I have gone through all of the code and if anyone can fix it then they must be the GOD.  Anyways, a user will click on a picture as long as it meets the deadline.  When an image is clicked it goes into the function 'teamback'.  It goes in there but it doesn't process the ajax request.  When the user selects an image it should update the database with the information being passed into the function.  I have posted all of the code.  Please HELP!!

This is the page where the user makes the picks...  (I'm sorry there is so much, there is even more php before this, but I'm 99% sure it isn't necessary.)

```
<?php
 // this starts the session 
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['userid'];

  $var = "";
 $varcontact = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/contact.php\");' class='three'>Contact</a>";
 // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
 if ($_SESSION['userid'] == "") {
        $var = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/register.html\");' class='two'>Register</a> | <a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php\");' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
    } else {
    $var = "Hello, ".$_SESSION['userid'] ."! | " . "<a href=\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/logout.php\" class='two'>Log Out</a>";
    }

 //this gets the name of the person selected in the league
 $uniqueid = $_GET["id"];
 $time = time();
 $timedeadline = 1344700055;

 //this connects to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","credential","credential");
mysql_select_db("yourfan_demo", $con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.indiana.edu/favicon.ico" />
        <title>YourFantasyFootballReality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenewarticle.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //*******COUNTDOWN TIMER******************//
        CountDownTimer('09/05/2012 8:30 PM', 'newcountdown');

    function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
    {
        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance <= 0) {
                //document.getElementById("newcountdown").style.font-size="1em";
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById("newcountdown").innerHTML = '00:00:00:00';
                document.getElementById("newcountdown").style.color="red";
                document.getElementById("newcountdown").style.border="3px dashed red";
                document.getElementById("newcountdown").style.bgColor="#FF63AC";

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById("newcountdown").innerHTML = days + ':';
            document.getElementById("newcountdown").innerHTML += hours + ':';
            document.getElementById("newcountdown").innerHTML += minutes + ':';
            document.getElementById("newcountdown").innerHTML += seconds + '';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }
    //****************************END OF COUNTDOWN TIMER****************//////
        //this is the user id session stored as a javascript variable
        var userid = "<?=$id?>";
        var uniqueid = "<?=$uniqueid?>";

        // Popup window code
        function newPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=450,width=600,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
        }
        function bigimg(x) {
            if (userid == uniqueid) {
            var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone! 
            var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000; 
            var deadline = '1344700055.000'; 
                //determines if user was on time..if not on time hover enlarge won't work
                if(myEpoch > deadline) {
                    x.style.height="65px";
                    x.style.width="85px";
                    //x.style.opacity="0.5";
                } else {}
            } else {}   
        }
        function defaultimg(x) {
            x.style.height="60px";
            x.style.width="80px";
            x.style.opacity="1.0";
        }
        function teamback(x, act) {
            if (uniqueid == userid) {
            var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone! 
            var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000; 
            var deadline = '1344700055.000';
                //determines if user was on time..if not on time submitting won't work
                if(myEpoch > deadline) {
                    // update the "actualone" image's source to the sending-image's source
                    var tn = x.id;
                    var sc = x.name;
                    //THIS MUST BE CHANGED BASED ON THE WEEK!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    var week = 1;
                    document.getElementById(act).src = x.src;
                    document.getElementById("curtime").innerHTML = myEpoch;
                    document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
                    document.getElementById("scenario").innerHTML = x.name;

                    //AJAX PART
                    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
                    try{
                        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } catch (e){
                        // Internet Explorer Browsers
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e){
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                    }}}
                    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
                    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                        //document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                    }
                    }
                    //here is where we will use the variables userid, tn, and sc
                    var queryString = "?userid=" + userid + "&tn=" + tn + "&sc=" + sc + "&week=" + week;
                    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "makepick.php" + queryString, true);
                    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

                } else {}           
            } else {}   
        }
        </script>

    </head>

                <body class="body">
                <!--Container to hold everything in the middle of page-->
                <div class="container">

                    <!--Facebook Like button-->
                    <iframe class="fb" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>                         

                    <!--Login and Register links-->
                    <div class="enter">
                        <?=$var?>
                    </div>

                    <!--Contains everything in the menu-->
                    <div class="menutest">
                    <!--the main menu links-->
                    <div id="navigation">
                        <ul>
                        <a class="topic" href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
                        <a class="topic" href="pickem.php"><li>Pick Em</li></a>
                        <a class="topic" href="projections.php"><li>Projections</li></a>
                        <a class="topic" href="stats.html"><li>Scoring Leaders</li></a>
                        <a class="topic" href="newarticle.php"><li>Articles</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--the list of scores-->
                    <table id="schedule" border="1">
                    <tr>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;DAL @NYG</a></td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;IND @CHI</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;ATL @KC</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;PHI @CLE</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;WAS @NO</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;STL @DET</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;NE @TEN</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;JAC @MIN</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;BUF @NYJ</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;MIA @HOU</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;SEA @ARI</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;SF @GB</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;CAR @TB</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;PIT @DEN</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;CIN @BAL</td>
                    <td><a class="one" href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=311002003">&nbsp;&nbsp;SD @OAK</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    </div>



                    <!--the espn ticker-->
                    <div class="ticker">
                    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.widgetserver.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">if (WIDGETBOX) WIDGETBOX.renderWidget('61d83c1a-939a-460b-8075-91c9e1473aff');</script>
<noscript>Get the <a href="http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/espns-bottom-line-version-20">ESPN's Bottom Line -  Version 2.0</a> widget and many other <a href="http://www.widgetbox.com/">great free widgets</a> at <a href="http://www.widgetbox.com">Widgetbox</a>! Not seeing a widget? (<a href="http://support.widgetbox.com/">More info</a>)</noscript>                    
                    --></div>

            <center><h1>Week 1</h1></center>
            <center><div style="font-size:1.5em; font-weight:bold;">Time Remaining to Make Picks</div></center>
            <center><div id="newcountdown" style="height:40px; width:300px; border:1; background-color:#BABABA; font-size:2em; border:2px ridge gray;"></div></center>
            <!--<center><iframe style="background-color:pink;" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i38ik9yz/n417/cf12/cm0/cu4/ct1/cs1/ca0/co1/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pct/tc66c/fs100/szw320/szh135/tatTime%20Remaining%20to%20Make%20Picks/tac000/tptTime%20Remaining%20to%20Make%20Picks/tpc000/iso2012-08-11T13:00:00/bas2/bat2/bacf00" frameborder="0" width="268" height="40"></iframe></center>-->
            <center><h4><a href="leaguehome.php"><?=$leaguename?></a> : <?=$id?></h4><?echo "Viewing " . $uniqueid . "'s Profile...";?></center>

        <center><div style="width:500px; color:white; font-weight:bold;">Week: <a class="two" href="2012week1.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">1 </a><a class="two" href="2012week2.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">2 </a><a class="two" href="2012week3.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">3 </a>
        <a class="two" href="2012week4.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">4 </a><a class="two" href="2012week5.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">5 </a><a class="two" href="2012week6.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">6 </a><a class="two" href="2012week7.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">7 </a>
        <a class="two" href="2012week8.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">8 </a><a class="two" href="2012week9.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">9 </a><a class="two" href="2012week10.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">10 </a><a class="two" href="2012week11.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">11 </a>
        <a class="two" href="2012week12.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">12 </a><a class="two" href="2012week13.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">13 </a><a class="two" href="2012week14.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">14 </a><a class="two" href="2012week15.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">15 </a>
        <a class="two" href="2012week16.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">16 </a><a class="two" href="2012week17.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">17 </a><a class="two" href="2012weekwc.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">WC </a><a class="two" href="2012weekdiv.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">DIV </a>
        <a class="two" href="2012weekconf.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">CONF </a><a class="two" href="2012weeksb.php?id=<? echo $uniqueid?>">SB </a> </div></center>

            <center><table border="1" style="background-color:white;">
                <tr>
                <th>Game</th>
                <th>Your Pick</th>
                <th>Picks Correct</th>
                <th>Points Earned</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><img id="cowboys" name="One" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualone')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="cowboys.gif"> vs <img id="giants" name="One" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualone')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="giants.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$One?>" id="actualone" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Ones?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Onep?></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><img id="colts" name="Two" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualtwo')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="colts.gif"> vs <img id="bears" name="Two" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualtwo')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="bears.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>5 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Two?>" id="actualtwo" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Twos?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Twop?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="eagles" name="Three" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualthree')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="eagles.gif"> vs <img id="browns" name="Three" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualthree')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="browns.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 4</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Three?>" id="actualthree" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Threes?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Threep?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="patriots" name="Four" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfour')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="patriots.gif"> vs <img id="titans" name="Four" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfour')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="titans.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 3</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Four?>" id="actualfour" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fours?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fourp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="falcons" name="Five" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfive')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="falcons.gif"> vs <img id="chiefs" name="Five" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfive')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="chiefs.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Five?>" id="actualfive" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fives?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fivep?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="jaguars" name="Six" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualsix')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="jaguars.gif"> vs <img id="vikings" name="Six" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualsix')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="vikings.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Six?>" id="actualsix" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sixs?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sixp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="redskins" name="Seven" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualseven')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="redskins.gif"> vs <img id="saints" name="Seven" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualseven')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="saints.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>5 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Seven?>" id="actualseven" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sevens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sevenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="bills" name="Eight" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualeight')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="bills.gif"> vs <img id="jets" name="Eight" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualeight')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="jets.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Eight?>" id="actualeight" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Eights?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Eightp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="rams" name="Nine" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualnine')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="rams.gif"> vs <img id="lions" name="Nine" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualnine')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="lions.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>4 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Nine?>" id="actualnine" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Nines?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Ninep?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="dolphins" name="Ten" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualten')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="dolphins.gif"> vs <img id="texans" name="Ten" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualten')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="texans.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>4 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Ten?>" id="actualten" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Tens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Tenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="49ers" name="Eleven" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualeleven')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="49ers.gif"> vs <img id="packers" name="Eleven" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualeleven')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="packers.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Eleven?>" id="actualeleven" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Elevens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Elevenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="seahawks" name="Twelve" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualtwelve')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="seahawks.gif"> vs <img id="cardinals" name="Twelve" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualtwelve')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="cardinals.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Twelve?>" id="actualtwelve" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Twelves?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Twelvep?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="panthers" name="Thirteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualthirteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="panthers.gif"> vs <img id="buccaneers" name="Thirteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualthirteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="buccaneers.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Thirteen?>" id="actualthirteen" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Thirteens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Thirteenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="steelers" name="Fourteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfourteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="steelers.gif"> vs <img id="broncos" name="Fourteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfourteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="broncos.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Fourteen?>" id="actualfourteen" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fourteens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fourteenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="bengals" name="fifteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfifteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="bengals.gif"> vs <img id="ravens" name="Fifteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualfifteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="ravens.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Fifteen?>" id="actualfifteen" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fifteens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Fifteenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                <td><img id="chargers" name="Sixteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualsixteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="chargers.gif"> vs <img id="raiders" name="Sixteen" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this, 'actualsixteen')" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="raiders.gif">
                <br><div style="background-color:gray; width:180px; height:20px"><center>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODDS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1</center></div></td>
                <td><img src="<?=$Sixteen?>" id="actualsixteen" style="width:85px; height:65px;"></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sixteens?></center></td>
                <td><center><?=$Sixteenp?></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><center>Totals</center></td><td></td><td><center><?=$Week_Selections?></center></td><td><b><center><?=$Week_Points?></center></b></td></tr>
            </table></center>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

And here is makepick.php where the ajax request updates the db...

```
<?php
//this connects to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","yourfan_jeengle","armyjoe");
mysql_select_db("yourfan_demo", $con);

$userid = $_GET["userid"];
$tn = $_GET["tn"];
$sc = $_GET["sc"];
$wk = $_GET["week"];

mysql_query("UPDATE `Week{$wk}_Picks` SET `$sc` = '$tn' WHERE UserID = '$userid'");
?>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you including jQuery in your page and then _not_ using it for Ajax? You can replace about 20 lines of your code with about 2 lines of jQuery. (Also, do you really have an error message "Your browser broke!"?)

Comment: I didn't know jquery at the time and was modeling this after a sample.  I have VERY LITTLE experience with jqurey and ajax..could you please show me how to do this if you can?

Comment: It's basically just `$.get(yourURL, yourData, functionToCallOnSuccess)`, or use `$.ajax()` to set more options. There is plenty of info on the [jQuery doco site](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), and some tutorials that cover Ajax here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the id of curtime, team, and scenario which don't exist.  THis is stopping the ajax from being executed.  Take out those lines and you'll be good.

```
   function teamback(x, act) {
        if (uniqueid == userid) {
        var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone! 
        var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000; 
        var deadline = '1344700055.000';
            //determines if user was on time..if not on time submitting won't work
            if(myEpoch > deadline) {
                // update the "actualone" image's source to the sending-image's source
                var tn = x.id;
                var sc = x.name;
                //THIS MUST BE CHANGED BASED ON THE WEEK!!!!!!!!!!!!
                var week = 1;
                document.getElementById(act).src = x.src;
                document.getElementById("curtime").innerHTML = myEpoch;
                document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
                document.getElementById("scenario").innerHTML = x.name;

                //AJAX PART
                var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
                try{
                    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e){
                    // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }}}
```